# Why does my Parse Query succeed in AppDelegate, but not in ViewController?

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfquery

For some reason, my Parse query succeeds, and returns objects, in my AppDelegate.Swift file. However, when I make the same call in `viewDidLoad` of the initial view controller, it fails.

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Thanks!

Here is my query:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Houses")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print("Succeeded")
            print(objects!.count)
        } else {
            print(error?.description)
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is the error message ?

Comment: There is no error message. the error returned by the query is nil, as well as the objects.

Comment: Are you sure Parse is initialised before you call this query ? If this viewcontroller is your root one this code can end up executing first before the App delegates are executed.

Comment: It is the root view controller, perhaps that is the issue. How can I tell if Parse is initialized before i call the query?

Comment: well just make sure this view controller is not the root one and test if my hypothesis is correct

Comment: That was it, the app delegate function wasn't called until after the viewDidLoad in the root view controller. Thanks so much. Can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED:** Thanks to @Mo Nazemi in comments.

Parse was not initialized before the query call was made in `viewDidLoad` of root view controller.