# Reloading NSTableView after downloading data

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I'm writing an app that will help me update my database on parse and I'm trying to load objects into an nstableview.

For whatever reason, I'm returning nil when I make the call in my viewcontroller so I moved the data into my appdelegate to get the objects.

```
let storyBoard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let myVC = storyBoard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier("teacher") as! ViewController

var teachers = [Teacher]()

let query = PFQuery(className: "TeacherList")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
    objects, error in
    if let objects = objects {
        for object in objects {
            let teacher = Teacher()
            teacher.name = object["name"] as! String
            teacher.email = object["email"] as! String
            teacher.subjectsTaught = object["subjectsTaught"] as! [String: String]
            teacher.category = object["category"] as! String
            teacher.uniqueID = object.objectId!
            teachers.append(teacher)
        }

    }
    print(teachers)
    myVC.teacherList = teachers
}
```

As you see, I pass this along to my VC. So I understand that I need to reload the data as viewDidLoad() will be called before the data has been downloaded. I've tried putting tableView.reloadData() in didSet for teacherList and just in case that's set before the viewloads, I even throw it in viewdidload.

```
var teacherList: [Teacher]? {
didSet {
    print("got set")
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.setDelegate(self)
    tableView.setDataSource(self)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

However, no matter what, my tableview is nil for anything that happens after viewdidload. I've also tried optional channing in my getSet.
I should also say that I'm brand new to OSX programming as I've done most of my programming for iOS.

I can put the query in my VC but whenever I run the query, I return nil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PFQuery` works asynchronously, the data is returned much later - in terms of computer speed – after `viewDidLoad` exits.

Reload the table view in the block right after the array has been populated on the main thread.

```
var teachers = [Teacher]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.setDelegate(self)
    tableView.setDataSource(self)
    let query = PFQuery(className: "TeacherList")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { [unowned self] (objects, error) in
      if let objects = objects {
        for object in objects {
            let teacher = Teacher()
            teacher.name = object["name"] as! String
            teacher.email = object["email"] as! String
            teacher.subjectsTaught = object["subjectsTaught"] as! [String: String]
            teacher.category = object["category"] as! String
            teacher.uniqueID = object.objectId!
            self.teachers.append(teacher)
        }
      }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    print(self.teachers)
  }
}
```

Comment: I was wondering if I need to reload the UI back on the main queue, however, my call to download objects is still returning nil. I'm not getting any objects from parse. Now, this seems like an error on my end but when I put the exact same block of code in my appdelegate, my objects come back.

Comment: Yes you have to because the background tasks usually work on a separate thread.

Comment: Basically the code is supposed to work. Is there a specific reason to instantiate the main controller programmatically rather than in Interface Builder? Maybe that's a timing issue. Add a print line to see when viewDidLoad is called.

Comment: The only reason I did that was because I couldn't get the parse objects downloaded in the VC so I though, well, I'll try it in the appdelegate and then just pass it along. When the query returns the objects in the appdelegate, I get a nice dictionary of data but when I run the exact same query in viewdidload in my VC, I return nil. I for the life of me can't figure out why there's a difference.

Comment: Okay, find the answer to that, just need to figure out how to fix it. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33262099/why-does-my-parse-query-succeed-in-appdelegate-but-not-in-viewcontroller)

Comment: It works! I put in another viewcontroller with a button that would bring up the nstable so the table wasn't my root VC and everything loaded and was awewsome. Thank you kind sir. (I did move the dispatch_async inside the block as well).